# SOAP xml in return - Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

I'm using k2SOAP for Android when dealing with webservices.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("ProjectID", 1);

SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try {

    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
    String resultString = result.toString();
}
```

I know there is nothing wrong with the code since it works with the w3 web service. But w3c returns a string as an answer this web service returns an XML. The answer I get back looks like this when I show it in log:

```
anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{element=an    yType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; 
element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; 
unique=anyType{selector=anyType{}; field=anyType{}; }; }; }; diffgram=anyType{}; }
```

Which basically is a lot of noise and I'm not sure on how to get the information from this or how I should parse it or. My ultimate goal is to put the information I get in to a local database but since I don't know how to get the information from the String I don't know put the info in the database.

So what I want to do is to somehow parse the information and put it in a local database which I already built the classes for.
How do I get the data from the SoapObject result?
There is a slight possibility the web service info is empty, but my question is still the same.

Comment: Hi Joakim, Have you find any way for parsing this type of response...if so,please provide some help...  is it possible to use any native parser of android ?

Comment: Still no answer, sry  Nandagopal T!

Comment: Hi Joakim, Hurray.... I found the solution buddy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two Things you need to change

1)Add this `"httpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");"`

line above  `"httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);"`

2) `String resultString = result.toString();`

Replace the above line with following one

`String resultString=httpTransport.responseDump;`

This will return response as xml formated String

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I had the same problem. Information is coming like above but not with xml format. Any additional help ?

Comment: You're probably using "SoapObject results=(SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;" to get the file. Use 

HttpTransportSE ht = getHttpTransportSE();
ht.responseDump;

and the file should come out in XML format.

Answer (score 2):

The provided answer did not work for me rather lines bellow worked for me. Try the following lines, hope this will give you data with XML tags,

```
httpTransport.debug=true; 
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
String ss=httpTransport.responseDump; 
Log.d("Result --- ", ss);
```

This will print the complete xml file which has been returned by the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this WAy .

```
try {

    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();


String element = ((SoapObject)result.getPropertySafely("schema")).getPropertySafely("element").toString();
```