# Not able to parse the response getting Invalid array range: 5 to 5

Tags: java, json, parsing, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a parser to parse the below response,the issue is i am able to parse only first table dataset not able to parse second or later table dataset,not sure where looping is going wrong.the xml response is like

```
anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; diffgram=anyType{NewDataSet=anyType{Table=anyType{RemMessage=Exeed Discount Limit on Invoice dated on 05/03/2015 for C SHAH , from 3 - Lokhandwala Showroom; InvM_Id=77693; DocType=3; PrmR_TypeId=3; PrmR_Id=1820; }; **Table=anyType{RemMessage=Exeed Discount Limit on Invoice dated on 14/03/2015 for G P SHAH , from 3 - Khar Showroom; InvM_Id=77800; DocType=3; PrmR_TypeId=3; PrmR_Id=1865; };** Table=anyType{RemMessage=Exeed Discount Limit on Invoice dated on 14/03/2015 for DOONGARSHI SHAH , from 3 - Khar Showroom; InvM_Id=77801; DocType=3; PrmR_TypeId=3; PrmR_Id=1866; }; }; }; }
```

my parsing code is not parsing entire response properly,The code is

```
public class KSoap2ResultParser {

    public static void parseBusinessObject(String input, Object output) throws NumberFormatException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException{
       System.out.println("input----> "  +input);
        Class theClass = output.getClass();
        Field[] fields = theClass.getDeclaredFields();

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            Type type=fields[i].getType();
            System.out.println("type--" +type);
            fields[i].setAccessible(true);

            //detect String
            if (fields[i].getType().equals(String.class)) {
                String tag =  fields[i].getName() + "=";   //"s" is for String in the above soap response example + field name for example Name = "sName"
                System.out.println("fff------------"+tag);
                if(input.contains(tag)){
                    String strValue = input.substring(input.indexOf(tag)+tag.length(), input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf(tag)));
                    System.out.println("RemMessage------------"+strValue);
                    if(strValue.length()!=0){
                        fields[i].set(output, strValue);
                    }
                }
            }

            //detect int or Integer
            if (type.equals(Integer.TYPE) || type.equals(Integer.class)) {
                String tag = fields[i].getName() + "=";  //"i" is for Integer or int in the above soap response example+ field name for example Goals = "iGoals"
                if(input.contains(tag)){
                    String strValue = input.substring(input.indexOf(tag)+tag.length(), input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf(tag)));
                    System.out.println("strvalue------------"+strValue);

                    if(strValue.length()!=0){
                        fields[i].setInt(output, Integer.valueOf(strValue));
                    }
                }
            }

            //detect float or Float
            if (type.equals(Float.TYPE) || type.equals(Float.class)) {
                String tag = "f" + fields[i].getName() + "=";
                if(input.contains(tag)){
                    String strValue = input.substring(input.indexOf(tag)+tag.length(), input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf(tag)));
                    if(strValue.length()!=0){
                        fields[i].setFloat(output, Float.valueOf(strValue));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

and i am calling from

```
String response=androidHttpTransport.responseDump;

SoapObject obj=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

for(int i=0; i < obj.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
    GetReminder rem = new GetReminder();
    KSoap2ResultParser.parseBusinessObject(obj.getProperty(i).toString(),rem);
    reminders.add(rem);
 }
```

there is an issue in parsing please help me to correct it.

Comment: When you log `System.out.println("input----> "  +input);`, do you have 3 lines, one for each `NewDataSet` array element?

Comment: acually i am getting arrayindex exception just after this line,has in you can see my GetReminder class has five fields and index is also coming has five ....,
 
pastebin.com/EngEcQqe

Comment: can u pls try to parse this using main() taking my response and classes has in pastebin

Answer (score 0):

First, FYI, the response you get is **not** XML.

You have 2 solutions to properly parse the response:

#### 1- Get the WS response as an actual XML

To do that see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421897/soap-xml-in-return-android). And then use a proper [XML DOM parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396834/dom-xml-parser-example) to process the response and build the Java objects.

#### 2- Do it directly with a SOAP api

Looking for the best way, I came across [this](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#Manual_Parsing_of_an_Array_of_into_an_POJO_array) with tips that are relevant to your problem. 
Look at [parsing array elements](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#Manual_Parsing_of_an_Array_of_into_an_POJO_array). In your case, you can change your code:
Change the line:

> ```
> KSoap2ResultParser.parseBusinessObject(obj.getProperty(i).toString(),rem);
> ```

by:

```
 KSoap2ResultParser.parseBusinessObject((SoapObject)obj.getProperty(i),rem);
```

And change the signature of method `parseBusinessObject(SoapObject pojoSoap, Object obj)`. Then in the method, for each type, e.g. for `String`:

> ```
> if(strValue.length()!=0){
>      fields[i].set(output, strValue);
>  }
> ```

by:

```
if(strValue.length()!=0){
     String fieldName = fields[i].getName();
     String fieldValue = pojoSoap.getProperty(fieldName).toString();
     fields[i].set(output, fieldValue);
}
```

Comment: can you please try running my code ,i am making some silly mistake but not sure what in looping in the parser for next values---http://pastebin.com/EngEcQqe,this is giving me arrayIndexOutOfBoundException while     Type type=fields[i].getType(); for next data

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ugk7Bu8D please let me know seriously i am stuck with this silly mistake

Comment: @mr-smith i came across this link of your solution i am following the same but causing an issue can u please check                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997680/how-to-do-the-parsing-of-soap-response

Comment: any input ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084207/parsing-webservice-anytype-response  ,can you try to parse this with looping for multiple entries